# How to work with form fields which have the same names?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I have the PDF file that contains a form with fields that have the same fields names. It’s has been done for sharing data in the document. For instance, I have contract and each page of this document must have the company name and I write company name in one form fields and it is copied for all pages in the current document, but when I try to read this document using `itext7` library I don’t get this data because `itext7` creates only one field with the field name and other is clean up.

```
PdfFormField field = acroform.getFormFields().values().get(0);
if(field.getFieldName().equals(“my_company”)) {
    List<PdfWidgetAnnotation> list = field.getWidgets();
    if(pdf.getPageNumber(list.get(0).getPage()) == 1).  { // because I have this text on page 1, but this code return page = 7, because is the last page of the document which contains this text field.
        …
    }
}
```

How can I read the fields with the same fields names using `itext7` library?

Comment: You only look at `list.get(0)`. Have you checked for other widgets, too? I.e. `list.get(1)`, `list.get(2)`, ...?

Comment: @mkl It's the only example I run by widget list using for each loop, but it is doesn't matter because in my case widget list has only one item. But the issue is that I can't get all fields or widget with the same name because of  ```itext``` library override this information. I found it in this post: http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Fields-with-same-name-td2990470.html

Comment: Please share the PDF in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to solve my issue. I got all the fields from `Catalog` that is placed in the `PdfDocument` class. The code looks like the following:

```
public List<PdfFormField> getFields() {
    final List<PdfFormField> pdfFormFields = new ArrayList<>();
    final PdfDictionary acroFormDict = pdf.getCatalog().getPdfObject().getAsDictionary(PdfName.AcroForm);
    if (acroFormDict != null) {
        final PdfArray fields = acroFormDict.getAsArray(PdfName.Fields);
        if(fields != null) {
            fillPdfFormFields(fields, pdfFormFields);
        }
    }
    return pdfFormFields;
}
private List<PdfFormField> fillPdfFormFields(PdfArray array, List<PdfFormField> fields) {
    array.forEach(pdfObject -> {
        final PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.makeFormField(pdfObject, pdfFile);
        fields.add(field);
        final PdfArray fieldKids = field.getKids();
        if (fieldKids != null) {
            fillPdfFormFields(fieldKids, fields);
        }
    });
    return fields;
}
```